# Pimcore Error(Symfony): No route found for "GET /"

Tags: symfony, get, routes, pimcore

[image: Click here for the img.]

Dont know what to do.. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no default Route. This is outlined in the Symfony docs. Take your time and you will work this out.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Your question lacks the required information to be able to fully understand the problem. When starting out change one thing at a time and take your time.

Good luck.